# Angular send complex object to C# Controller

Tags: c#, angular, list, http

I've got a service that I use to send requests to an MVC controller in C#.

This has been working fine until now that I have a complex object I'm trying to send.  The param `postDto` in C# is always null. I've tried a few different solutions but haven't been able to solve this issue.  If I remove the list from the object, the object comes across successfully. Any help would be appreciated.

**service.ts**

```
...
post$(postDto: MyTSPostDto): Observable<MyTSDto> {
    return this.http.post<MyTSDto>(
        location.origin + '/api/mycontroller',
        postDto,
        { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) }
    ).pipe(
        map((response: MyTSDto) => response)
    );
}
```

**myTSPostDto.ts**

```
export class MyTSPostDto {
    firstPostDto: FirstPostDto;
    secondPostDto: SecondPostDto;
    thirdPostDtos: ThirdPostDto[] = [];
}
```

**postDto.cs**

```
public class PostDto
{
    public FirstPostDto FirstPostDto { get; set; }
    public SecondPostDto SecondPostDto { get; set; }
    public List<ThirdPostDto> ThirdPostDtos { get; set; }
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
...
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyDto), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Migrate([FromBody] PostDto postDto)
{
...
```

Comment: Look at the browser's network tab and see what is *actually* being sent to the server. Compare that with what the server expects.

Comment: You need to keep your typecript `MyTSPostDto` variables [names exactly same] and their types same as C# `PostDto`. Please make that change and try.

Comment: @user2216584, I changed the types to match (both arrays) but it still came across as null.  The names are already identical.

Comment: Again, you need to do a little debugging here. Look at the network tab of your browsers debug window. You should be able to inspect the data of the http message body. What is actually being sent?

Comment: names are not identical `firstPostDto` vs `FirstPostDto`. Also, the type of `firstPostDto` and another variable should be structurally the same as  `PostDtoTypeA` and `PostDtoTypeB`

Comment: @user2216584 I've never needed to do that on any other request to get it to work.  As I stated, this works if I remove the list from my PostDto.  The types are identical, they just have slightly differing names between angular and C#

Comment: @Igor, I was just responding to user2216584 since their suggestion was a quick check.  Checking on the Network tab, I see my inner types being sent as usual, and my new list type being send as an array (as it should be from the ts postDto).  I've updated my type in the C# PostDto to be an array to match the incoming type, but the object param is still null.

Comment: @user2216584 For kicks I just changed my C# postdto member names to be identical in casing and the incoming object was still null.  I also renamed the inner postDto types to be identical to the angular postDto types; the parameter was still null.  I checked again removing the lists, and everything came across that wasn't a list.

Comment: I am far from an Angular dev, but should this `return this.http.post<MyTSDto>` not be `return this.http.post<MyTSPostDto>`?

Comment: @SimonWilson nah thats just the return type its expecting.  My API will return a different response with that dto within it.

Comment: ok, sorry :) I am learning Typescript though...I'll return and answer you in a couple of months.

Comment: @SimonWilson No worries, good luck on your coding journey!  Feel free to come back if you figure out why this happens.

Comment: In the future, once you made your backend and run it, your schemas should be visible in your generated documentation (Swagger if you use it). You can copy those names in your frontend DTO to make sure the mapping is done correctly and you can prevent typo's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had some model validation happening in C# that was causing the postDto parameter to come across as null.  As soon as I fixed up my model to provide valid inner models, then everything started working.